# How can I make a dynamic font-size base on parent element's size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

Here is my code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

I didn't set `font-size` property to it. Now I want to know, can I set a dynamic `font-size` to it? I mean, I want a bigger `font-size` for this one:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Because of bigger both `width` and `height` for `<li>` in second code snippet. Is doing that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `vw`? See fiddle and resize the window https://jsfiddle.net/d456eLwt/

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  font-size: 5vw;
  line-height: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```